# No regions displayed in the dropdown when setting up external identities for IAP backend service on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-identity, google-cloud-console, google-cloud-load-balancer, google-cloud-identity

I'm trying to set up Google Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP) to use external identities. However, when I try to choose a region during the process, the dropdown shows "No items to display" and doesn't list any available regions.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Navigate to **Security -> Identity-Aware Proxy** in the Google Cloud
   Console.
2. Choose one of the backend services resources.
3. Initiate the process
   for "Use external identities for authorization".
4. Select "Create a sign-in page for me" under the "Login page"
   section.
5. When prompted to choose a region, the dropdown is empty and displays
   the message "No items to display".

[image]

**Expected behavior:**

I expected to see a list of available regions in the dropdown to select from.

**What I've tried:**

- Reloading the console.
- Clearing the browser cache.
- Trying this on multiple GCP projects.

Has anyone else encountered this issue or know of a solution or workaround?

Comment: This is a Known issue which is already faced by multiple customers and the issue is raised in PIT, Seems the team is working on this issue. You can follow this [Public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/301136526) for further updates on this issue.

Comment: Feel free to update the status of the question. Let me know if the below answer helps to resolve your issue? I am happy to help you if you have any further queries.

Comment: Seems the reported issue was resolved. Please verify if the problem has been resolved from your end as well.

Answer (score 0):

For better community visibility posting my comment as an answer.

- This is a Known issue which is already faced by multiple customers
  and the issue raised in PIT. This is pending with the product
  engineering team and they are working on this issue and currently
  there is no ETA. You can follow this [Public issue
  tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/301136526) for further
  updates on this issue and by giving the upvote to that issue you can
  show that you're impacted. You can also provide your comments or
  inputs to them in that link.
- Refer to this official GCP
  [article](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enable-external-identities)
  on how to configure Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP) to use external
  identities.

**UPDATE:**

The product engineering team has resolved the reported issue. Please verify if the problem has been resolved from your end as well.

If you encounter any further issues or have any additional concerns, please don't hesitate to create a new issue on the [IssueTracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) providing a detailed description of your issue.